# failed to create a map: 22 Invalid argument

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I compiled the sample bpf programs which is provided here - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/samples/bpf  using the instructions. For most of the program while execution I am getting this error:

```
sudo ./sockex1  
failed to create a map: 22 Invalid argument
```

I have checked the relevant BPF flags on my system and they are correctly set. I am using linux-4.17 source code.

Comment: The example still works for me on kernel 4.18rc2. Did you get any particular error when compiling the example? Is your machine also running 4.17, or something older? Did you change the code of the sample? Did you try to strace the program to see if you can get more information?

Comment: @Qeole There was no error while compiling the examples. But my machine is running older kernel. Kernel version: 4.13.0-45-generic  . I have strace ouptut here: https://pastebin.com/g1cyV1CL

Comment: @Qeole Do I need to install kernel version - 4.17 on my machine also ?

Comment: I would expect this example to work fine on 4.13 as well. You're sure your system has the correct flags then? Did you manage to load another eBPF program or map, from any other example?

Comment: I have flags set like this:                                                                                      `grep BPF config-4.13.0-45-generic  
    CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y  
    CONFIG_BPF=y  
    CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y  
   CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m  
   CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=m  
   CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=m  
   CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y  
   CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y  
   CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y  
   CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y  
   CONFIG_TEST_BPF=m`

Comment: Ok, I think the `CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL` is the only one that matters here, so that looks good. Any other program / map that you manage to load, one way or another? I'm sorry, I don't really know how to debug more here :(. You might want to try with kernel 4.17 just in case, if you get no better answer here or debug info…

Answer (score 1):

Recompile your kernel with `CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y` flag which is required for `SOCKMAP` support.